# Can't restore previous data after update

Tags: docker, cassandra, thingsboard

After updating my thingsboard docker image from v2.4.0 to v2.4.1, the new thingsboard container doesn't have any of my previous data, in my host dir I have the ~/.mytb-data directory with 8Gb of size, there is a way to restore that data to my container or another database, I really need to get that data from ~/.mytb-data

This is the docker image that I using: `thingsboard/tb-cassandra`

The update process:

`$ docker pull thingsboard/tb-cassandra`

`$ docker stop mytb`

`$ docker run -it -v ~/.mytb-data:/data --rm thingsboard/tb-cassandra upgrade-tb.sh`

`$ docker rm mytb`

`$ docker run -it -p 9090:9090 -p 1883:1883 -p 5683:5683/udp -v ~/.mytb-data:/data -v ~/.mytb-logs:/var/log/thingsboard --name mytb --restart always thingsboard/tb-cassandra`

Comment: do not use `~` try $HOME/.... instead

Comment: I also try to run my thingsboard image without the update, but still, I don't get my data back